# How to initialize Ninject from Xamarin.Android Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, ninject

I am trying to initialize Ninject from the MainActivity of Xamarin.Android App, but it's throwing below exception on StandardKernel:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1

I have two project's, 1> SharedLibrary (.Net Standard 2.0) and Xamarin.Android Project

Code in SharedLibrary:

```
public class Dependencies : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IItemRepository>().To<TodoItemRepositoryADO>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}


 public class NinjectContainer
  {
        public static StandardKernel Container;

        public static void Load()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new Dependencies());
            Container = kernel;
        }
  }



public class AppInitializer
    {
        public void Intialize()
        {
            NinjectContainer.Load();
        }
    }
```

Code In MainActivity:

```
AppInitializer appInitializer = new AppInitializer();
appInitializer.Intialize();
```

StackTrace:

> 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in
>   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C# 0x1 in
>   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException   C# 0x26 in
>   object.e813dbd6-dc94-4712-a75f-815827c29a49   C# 0xD in
>   System.IO.Path.Combine    C# 0x7 in Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader. C# 0x4D
>   in
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator.MoveNext    C#
>   0x54 in
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator.MoveNext   C#
>   0x3E in
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator.MoveNext   C#
>   0x75 in
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator.MoveNext   C#
>   0x2C in System.Linq.Lookup.Create  C# 0x12 in
>   System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable.GetEnumerator    C# 0x5A in
>   Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules  C# 0xC in
>   Ninject.KernelBase.Load   C# 0xBC in Ninject.KernelBase..ctor C# 0xC in
>   Ninject.KernelBase..ctor  C# 0x2 in Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor  C# 0xF
>   in SharedCode.NinjectContainer.Load at
>   C:\Users\dishah\source\repos\ToDo\SharedCode\NinjectContainer.cs:11,13    C#
>   0x1 in SharedCode.AppInitializer.Intialize at
>   C:\Users\dishah\source\repos\ToDo\SharedCode\AppInitializer.cs:11,13  C#
>   0x8C in ToDo.MainActivity.OnCreate at
>   C:\Users\dishah\source\repos\ToDo\ToDo\MainActivity.cs:53,13  C# 0x11
>   in Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_    C# 0x17 in
>   object.e813dbd6-dc94-4712-a75f-815827c29a49   C#

Comment: Could you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: @JanMuncinsky Updated my post with StackTrace

Comment: Including external code?

Comment: @JanMuncinsky Sorry, I missed that. Included External code as well.

Comment: Okay, Finally I figured out the issue after spending almost 4 days. It was throwing error due to some path issue, I moved project to different path and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build the **StandardKernel** with **NinjectSettings** :

```
 var settings = new Ninject.NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false };
 Kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, new ViewModelsModule());
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but I already found the solution for this issue. Please have a look at my last comment in the post itself.